# Depth First Traversal with Javascript

Tags: javascript, tree

I have been reading the following article:
https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/data-structures-with-javascript-tree--cms-23393

This sets up the following classes and methods.

```
function Node(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.parent = null;
    this.children = [];
}

function Tree(data) {
    var node = new Node(data);
    this._root = node;
}

Tree.prototype.traverseDF = function(callback) {
    (function recurse(currentNode) {
        for (var i = 0, length = currentNode.children.length; i < length; i++) {
            recurse(currentNode.children[i]);
        }

        callback(currentNode);
    })(this._root);

};
var tree = new Tree('one');

tree._root.children.push(new Node('two'));
tree._root.children[0].parent = tree;

tree._root.children.push(new Node('three'));
tree._root.children[1].parent = tree;

tree._root.children.push(new Node('four'));
tree._root.children[2].parent = tree;

tree._root.children[0].children.push(new Node('five'));
tree._root.children[0].children[0].parent = tree._root.children[0];

tree._root.children[0].children.push(new Node('six'));
tree._root.children[0].children[1].parent = tree._root.children[0];

tree._root.children[2].children.push(new Node('seven'));
tree._root.children[2].children[0].parent = tree._root.children[2];
```

This tree looks like

```
 one
 ├── two
 │   ├── five
 │   └── six
 ├── three
 └── four
     └── seven
```

So when we finally make our traversal call

```
tree.traverseDF(function(node) {
    console.log(node.data)
});
```

It returns:

```
five
six
two
three
seven
four
one
```

This broke my understanding of "depth first". If you google depth first, wikipedia has the following image:

[image]

Under this picture it feels like the previous code should print:

```
one
two
five 
six
```

According to wikipedia:

> One starts at the root (selecting some arbitrary node as the root in the case of a graph) and explores as far as possible along each branch before backtracking

The current implementation in this question, actually prints starting from the bottom, youngest children and moves up instead of top to bottom how its defined by wikipedia. Can anyone help me understand what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does perform a depth first search, but there is still flexibility in deciding when a node is to be considered "visited": is it on its first encounter, or while backtracking?

If you move your `console.log` before the loop, you'll get what you expected:

```
Tree.prototype.traverseDF = function(callback) {
    (function recurse(currentNode) {
        callback(currentNode); // <-----
        for (var i = 0, length = currentNode.children.length; i < length; i++) {
            recurse(currentNode.children[i]);
        }
    })(this._root);
};
```

There is no right or wrong here.

There are in fact three flavours. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Depth-first_search):

- pre-order (what you expected)
- in-order (relevant for binary trees)
- post-order (your version)

Comment: May I ask how this is self terminating? Is it because when there are no longer children the for loop is bypassed and the callback is invoked? I forgot to ask this as part of the question.

Comment: It is self terminating because there is no recursive call on the leaves of the tree, which have no children, and so the loop does not have any iteration for those leaves. In that case the only thing that happens is the call of the callback function, and the recursion backtracks to the previous call. There the loop will go to its next iteration, ...etc.