# javascript make recursive array walk and update some internal value (pointer)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got the following array:

```
let arr = [
{
    children: [
        {
            children: [],
            current: true //pointer is at the first element with no children
        },
        {
            children: [
                {
                    children: [],
                    current: false  //if the pointer is here, next item should be the next parent`s first child (without children)
                },
                {
                    children: [
                               {
                                  current: false,
                                  children: []
                               },
                               {
                                current: false,
                                children: []
                               }
                              ],

                },
                {
                    children: [],
                    current: false 
                }               
            ]
        },
        {
            children: [],
            current: false
        },      
    ]

},
{
    children: [],
    current: false
},
{
    children: [],
    current: false
},
{
    children: [],
    current: false
},
];
```

I am creating an array walker (tree walker) so that the user could walk through it back and forth. So for example, when the user hits forward button, the pointer (`current`) moves to the next position among children in array, making this element `current` pointer `false` and next element `current` pointer true. If there is no more children in current parent, pointer moves to the next parent and makes `current` first child there (which does not have its children). User can only move among children which dont have their children (their `children` element is empty or there is no children at all), a parent with children cannot be selected and made `current`. My code is as follows:

```
makeNextQuestionCurrent = (arr, currentChanged = false) => {
    arr.some(
        (item, index) => {
            if(item.children && item.children.length > 1){
                if(!currentChanged){
                    this.makeNextQuestionCurrent(item.children);
                }
            }else{
                  if(item.current && !currentChanged){
                     item.current = false;
                     if(arr[index + 1]){      
                         arr[index + 1].current = true;
                                currentChanged  = true;
                     }else{
                           //some logic should be here...
                          }
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

So my problem begins when I reach the end of children of a parent. When the child is last, I cannot jump to next parent children. Any ideas how to fix it would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: What you're showing is a tree, that you implemented using arrays. If you're having trouble writing a tree walker, my first recommendation would be to pick a better data structure: use an actual tree, so that calling a function on a node will respond either directly or delegate the response by calling one (or more of) its own child(ren). Where does the data you're showing come from? (e.g. did you make it do that, or is that data you don't control).

Comment: thank you for comment. could you provide an example of such tree data structure? may be there is some example of such tree walker?

Comment: It kind of depends: is this homework, or are you working on your own project, or are you doing paid work and this is part of it? Because the answer to your question is radically different between those three.

Comment: its a project, there is a list of topics with back and forward buttons for user to navigate among them

Comment: Then the answer is "this is called depth-first tree traversal", so with those terms, google and SO will find you what you're looking for. In fact, you probably just want to read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612674/depth-first-traversal-with-javascript  and then if you have more questions, web searching should now work fine, since you now know what words to look for.

Comment: And I have simple iterator for this https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/HTM_HTA/JSON_Node_Iterator_IIFE.js it has DepthFirst predefined, also GoDown and pred/parent/next links self maintained, no more recursion, etc. needed... Or standalone one having also BreadthFirst and lot of other methods https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/HTM_HTA/JSON_Iterator_IIFE.js

Comment: thank you for your advice. Could you please show some example how this iterator could be used?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I disagree with your implication that the OP's given structure isn't "an actual tree". It is a perfectly valid tree structure, with a root node, `arr` that has zero or more children, which in turn have zero or more children. As long as there are no cycles, it is a valid tree. Yes, there are other forms that may or may not be better depending on the context.

Comment: That's not even remotely what I implied, I said it _was_ a tree, implemented using plain arrays, with the implication being that if you're still new to programming, then in modern JS that's a great way to get confused compared to using a dedicated tree node data structure with class code in which you can implement tree walking as "do what you need to do locally, then pass on responsibility". It's not that this isn't a tree, it's that they're getting confused by walking through their data structure, and the solution to that is almost _always_: change the data structure you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answered your own question:

> So my problem begins when I reach the end of children of a parent. When the child is last, I cannot jump to next parent children.

You need a way to back up out of branches of the tree when you are done walking that branch. There are two ways you can do this:

1. Add a pointer to each child pointing to its parent, OR
2. Have your tree walker keep track of parents (and their parents) using a `stack` data structure.

You would go with option 1 if you want to maintain your current strategy of keeping your walking state within the tree itself. **But this is a very bad idea**:

- It clutters up a data structure with program state that should be independent.
- It results in complicated code, as yours is.
- It is both memory and CPU inefficient.
- It only allows one tree walker to operate at a time.

If you decide to disentangle your walker state from your tree data as I suggest, you can go with either option 1 or option 2.

Here is an implementation of an option 2 tree walker:

```
class TreeWalker {
  currentNode
  currentChildIdx
  parentStack

  constructor (treeRoot) {
    this.currentNode = treeRoot
    this.currentChildIdx = -1
    this.parentStack = []
  }

  next () {
    // walk until a leaf node is found or we hit the end (terminal conditions are return stmts inside the loop)
    while (true) {
      const currentNode = this.currentNode
      const currentChildIdx = ++this.currentChildIdx
      if (currentNode.children && currentChildIdx < currentNode.children.length) {
        // we have more children; advance to the nex
        const child = currentNode.children[currentChildIdx]
        if (child.children) {
          // the next child itself has children; save state at this level, then descend
          this.parentStack.push({ node: currentNode, childIdx: currentChildIdx })
          this.currentNode = child
          this.currentChildIdx = -1
        } else {
          // the next child is a leaf; return it
          return child
        }
      } else if (this.parentStack.length > 0) {
        // no more children; back out to a parent.
        let p = this.parentStack.pop()
        this.currentNode = p.node
        this.currentChildIdx = p.childIdx
      } else {
        // back at root, all done
        return null
      }
    }
  }

  previous () {
    // I'll leave this one for you.
  }

}
```

TreeWalker assumes a consistent tree structure including having a root node that is the same structure as any other node.
I *does not* store walk state in the tree, so `current:` was all removed.

```
let root = {
  val: 'branch a',
  children: [
    {
      val: 'leaf 1'
    },
    {
      val: 'branch b',
      children: [
        {
          val: 'leaf 2'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 'branch c',
      children: [
        {
          val: 'leaf 3'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I left some work for you: ;)

- `previous()`
- returning the root node if it is also a leaf node.